# Using a WebClient to download a file, but being able to get the download information in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class DownloadStuff
    Dim downloader As New WebClient()
    Private Sub Progress_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Progress.Validated
        AddHandler downloader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadChangedHandler

        Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.example.com/example.txt")
        downloader.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "C:\example.txt")
    End Sub
    Private Sub DownloadChangedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Progress.Maximum = CInt(e.TotalBytesToReceive)
        Progress.Value = CInt(e.BytesReceived)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code, but the DownloadProgressChanged event is NEVER fired. (I am using an example URL here, but it is the same basic stuff)

What am I doing wrong? Progress is a ProgressBar.

This is in VB.net.

On MSDN, they mentioned something about overriding GetWebRequest, but I have no idea how to do that or what to do.

UPDATE: Still no progress, I simply cannot figure out how to make the handler fire.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgressCallback
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("..."), "data.txt")

End Sub

Private Sub DownloadProgressCallback( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)

    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage)

End Sub
```

Everytime I see `AddHandler` and `Handles` I feel dizzy.

Comment: Didn't work >.> http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ <--- is what I tried

Comment: That is what I had essentially, note that the callback is never executed, ever.